# QPropertyAnimation on QGraphicsPathItem

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt5, qgraphicsitem, qobject

I am trying to animate the color of a QGraphicsPathItem. In the Qt docs they say you can animate a QGraphicsItem if you subclass the item you want to animate. This is what Qt Documentation says (from [Animations and the Graphics View Framework](http://When%20you%20want%20to%20animate%20QGraphicsItems)):

> When you want to animate QGraphicsItems, you also use
> QPropertyAnimation. However, QGraphicsItem does not inherit QObject. A
> good solution is to subclass the graphics item you wish to animate.
> This class will then also inherit QObject. This way,
> QPropertyAnimation can be used for QGraphicsItems. The example below
> shows how this is done. Another possibility is to inherit
> QGraphicsWidget, which already is a QObject.
>
> Note that QObject must be the first class inherited as the meta-object
> system demands this.

I tried to do this but my program crashes when it creates a new 'Edge' class because of this reason.

My Edge class with QObject:

```
class Edge(QObject, QGraphicsPathItem):

    def __init__(self, point1, point2):
        super().__init__()
        self.point1 = point1
        self.point2 = point2
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.white, 2, Qt.SolidLine))

    def create_path(self, radius):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(self.point1.x() + radius, self.point1.y() + radius)
        path.lineTo(self.point2.x() + radius, self.point2.y() + radius)

        return path
```

Comment: PyQt doesn't work well with multiple inheritance of Qt Objects - it generally fails or cause the program to hang. If you need to use a property *of* the item, subclass QGraphicsObject and add the QGraphicsPathItem as children *item* of it (you can create a `pyqtProperty()` used as getter/setter for the item), otherwise use a simple QVariantAnimation.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of QObject inheritance is not applicable to python since multiple inheritance is only available in some cases and that is not the case with QGraphicsItem. One possible solution is to implement animation using composition with QVariantAnimation.

```py
class Edge(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, point1, point2):
        super().__init__()
        self.point1 = point1
        self.point2 = point2
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.white, 2, Qt.SolidLine))

        self.animation = QVariantAnimation()
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.handle_valueChanged)
        self.animation.setStartValue(QColor("blue"))
        self.animation.setEndValue(QColor("red"))
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)

    def create_path(self, radius):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(self.point1.x() + radius, self.point1.y() + radius)
        path.lineTo(self.point2.x() + radius, self.point2.y() + radius)
        return path

    def start_animation(self):
        self.animation.start()

    def handle_valueChanged(self, value):
        self.setPen(QPen(value), 2, Qt.SolidLine)
```